# Is this an exception to Newton's Second Law of Motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, projectile, relative-motion

If a ball in an experiment is dropped from two different heights, 6 feet and 12 feet, why would we need to exert more force when we catch the ball that is dropped from the height of 12 feet? According to Newton's 2nd Law of Motion, the force that we exert on an object is not dependent to height, only the mass and acceleration, (let's say the acceleration of both flight is g; they are free falling bodies). So, is this an exception to the Newton's 2nd Law of Motion?

I am thinking about velocity, because the ball has greater velocity when it is dropped from 12 feet of height, but the formula of force is still

$$ F = ma$$

So I believe that velocity should not be taken into consideration here?

Comment: There are no exceptions to Newton's second law, which why it is a law.

Comment: Your statements make no sense. You  exert no force when dropping a ball.

Comment: I edited it. 'When we catch the ball that is dropped'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Force that you apply to catch the ball depends on mass and acceleration BUT acceleration depends on change of velocity.

When you want to catch the ball, the final velocity of the ball is zero. Thus, the acceleration depends on the initial velocity (initial = when the ball touches your hand) and the time that it takes until your hand and the ball come to rest.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't include it in my post but what if the acceleration of both flight/fall is $g=9.8 m/s^2$?

Comment: When they are both in free fall

Comment: The problem has two parts: the free fall part and the catching part. 9.8 corresponds to the acceleration during the free fall not during the catching part.

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the ball from 12 feet, when it hits your hand, it is moving faster. This should be obvious from the kinematic equations. Let's call this speed $v_1$. Comparatively, let's call the speed when you drop the ball from 6 feet $v_2$.

Assuming when you "catch" the ball you bring it to rest, then in the first case, the acceleration is $(v_1 - 0)/t$, where $t$ is the time it takes for you to bring the ball to rest (usually a fraction of a second). In the second case it is $(v_2-0)/t$. Since $v_1 > v_2$, the first acceleration is larger than the second. Accordingly, by Newton's second law, you need to exert more force.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't include it in my post but what if the acceleration of both flight/fall is $g=9.8 m/s^2$?

Comment: When they are both in free fall

Comment: @JordanG the acceleration due to free-fall is what makes $v_1 > v_2$. There is a second acceleration when you bring the ball to rest. The calculations in the 2nd paragraph of the answer all involve the second acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a force when you counter gravity, and a force when you slow the ball down to zero velocity.

When you catch the ball, you counter the F=m9.8 gravitational force with an equal and opposite reaction force. This force does not however stop the ball, it merely stops it from falling faster - the ball is "still" moving at whatever velocity it was the moment you countered gravity.

That velocity is different depending on the height at which the ball was dropped. Assuming the time it takes to slow the ball down to zero is the same for both sceneries, slowing the 6f ball down to zero takes less less force than slowing the 12f ball.

There is more velocity to take away from the faster ball, and so the force to stop the faster ball is larger - but the force to take away the effect of gravity is the same for both.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Newton's second law is this :

$$F= \frac{dP}{dt}$$,

And for a constant mass, $dP= m dv$ , where $v$ is the velocity of the moving body..

[Newton's second law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) states that the **force applied on an object is directly proportional to the rate of change of momentum** of that object.

Also , the one falling from $12$ feet gains greater velocity just before you catch it and thus it has greater momentum just before it comes to you and so you need to apply a greater force to stop it than the one falling from $6$ feet.

Hope it helps .

Comment: Actually the 2nd law is $$F_{\rm total} = \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} p$$ or the net force equals the rate of change of momentum.

Comment: Downvoters please please please share their knowledge.. might be helpful and something new for me (thanks for downvoting).. :)

Comment: I agree, and for the record, I did not downvote your answer.